# Prove for any vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I've got to prove for any vector given, $\vec{x} = [x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}]^{T} \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$ that it's true that:
$| x_{1} + \dots + x_{n} | \leqslant \sqrt{n} \cdot \| x \| $
Please give me some hints for that. I know that in this case: $ \| x \| = \sqrt{| x_{1}|^2 + \dots + | x_{n} |^{2}}$, but what's that giving me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an application of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$\left \vert \vec{x} \cdot \vec{y} \right \vert \leq \left \Vert \vec{x} \right \Vert_2 \left \Vert \vec{y} \right \Vert_2$$
Taking $\vec{y} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\end{bmatrix}^T$, we obtain
$$\left \vert x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n \right \vert \leq \sqrt{n} \left \Vert \vec{x} \right \Vert_2$$

---

In fact we can obtain a stronger inequality by setting $\vec{y} = \begin{bmatrix} \text{sign}(x_1) & \text{sign}(x_2) & \cdots & \text{sign}(x_n)\end{bmatrix}^T$.

This gives us
$$\left \vert x_1 \right \vert + \left \vert x_2 \right \vert + \cdots + \left \vert x_n \right \vert \leq \sqrt{n} \left \Vert \vec{x} \right \Vert_2$$